# ASP .NET Core сервер с UDP клиентами

Tags: c#, сокет, asp.net-core

Есть `ASP .NET Core` сервер, в котором есть некоторый `REST api`.
Необходимо реализовать возможность подключаться клиентам через `UDP` (сокеты).
Различные библиотеки, такие как `SignalR`, использовать нельзя, ибо приложение-клиент находится на платформе, где нет соответствующей библиотеки, но поддерживает подключение через сокеты.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ну если библиотеки использовать нельзя, тогда вам придется писать очень много кода вручную. И как это вообще должно работать, если http не может работать поверх datagram layer?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, на сервере можно использовать любые бибилотеки, если не требуют дополнительных библиотек на клиенте. А работать должно по сути просто параллельно. API запросы используются для одних задач, UDP подключение - для других.

Comment: Собственно, берете класс [UdpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) и [используете](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-udp-services).

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, как мне это совместить с ASP .NET. Ну вот пример: Подключается клиент через api запрос, ну авторизируется там и всё такое, а затем он должен перейти с http запросов на UDP подключение. Я не понимаю как это делается с архитектурной точки зрения.

Comment: @SUDALV Ну через API сервер проверяет авторизацию, если все нормально, то выдает например токен или ключ шифрования(если требуется защитить просмотр трафика), номер порта (если динамический). Далее клиент переключается на UDP и шлет данные используя токен/ключ.